# Location of gradle gui settings

Tags: user-interface, settings, gradle

When I start the gui with `gradle --gui`, I can export and import my settings on the Favorites tab.  It will be written to a `*.favorite-tasks` in the selected folder, but it won't be loaded next time I start the gui.  The [userguide](http://gradle.org/current/docs/userguide/tutorial_gradle_gui.html) says "It is preferable to run this command from your gradle project directory so that the settings of the UI will be stored in your project directory", but I can't see any new file created.  I checked the `~/.gradle` and `<project>/.gradle` directories.  So where is this settings file located by default?  Shall I add an entry to my `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: what version of Gradle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *Gradle 1.1* it works just fine. It creates `gradle-app.setting` file in the project's folder after running `gradle --gui`. May be you have permission problems?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <setting name="task-tab"> 
    <setting name="show-description" value="true"/> 
  </setting>  
  <setting name="favorites-tab"> 
    <setting name="favorites"> 
      <setting name="favorite"> 
        <setting name="full-command-line" value="clean build"/>  
        <setting name="display-name" value="clean build"/>  
        <setting name="show-output" value="false"/> 
      </setting>  
      <setting name="favorite"> 
        <setting name="full-command-line" value="generate"/>  
        <setting name="display-name" value="generate"/>  
        <setting name="show-output" value="true"/> 
      </setting> 
    </setting> 
  </setting>  
  <setting name="command_line-tab"/>  
  <setting name="setup-tab"> 
    <setting name="setup"> 
      <setting name="custom-gradle-executor"/>  
      <setting name="current-directory" value="...."/>  
      <setting name="log-level" value="LIFECYCLE"/> 
    </setting> 
  </setting>  
  <setting name="Application_window-id"> 
    <setting name="window_x" value="60"/>  
    <setting name="window_y" value="60"/>  
    <setting name="window_width" value="780"/>  
    <setting name="window_height" value="800"/>  
    <setting name="extended-state" value="0"/> 
  </setting>  
  <setting name="main_panel"> 
    <setting name="current-tab" value="Task Tree"/> 
  </setting> 
</root>
```